# Split android screen and do navigation only in the 2nd part

Tags: java, android, split

I'm splitting my android screen/fragment into 2 parts like top half and bottom half. I did this by putting two `LinearLayouts` inside the parent `LinearLayout`.
In the Top Half, I've kept some textviews and buttons and dont want to change this part.
In the Bottom Half, there is a `button B`. Onclick of this `Button B`, I want to be navigated to some different page(or view) such that the Top Half remains unchanged and only the bottom part gets changed.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DifferentActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can do this by creating a DifferentActivity class(as above) in which again I'll have to divide it into 2 parts and copy paste code of the Top Half part and making the new changes in the Bottom Half Part.
But suppose in the mainActivity Bottom Half part, there are many buttons, each one navigating to a different view, then for each view I'll have to create one Activity consisting of 2 parts, including the fixed Top half part.

**Is there any other way such that navigation(onClick Button B) changes happen only in the Bottom Part while keeping the Top Part fixed**.

My goal is just to change the appearance/UI of the bottom part on clicking the `Button B` present in the Bottom part, do whatever you can, go to different activity or make changes in the same parent activity, do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Change the two LinearLayouts into 2 separate fragments.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.FragmentA"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
              android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.FragmentB"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now inside your FragmentB add a onClickListener to your **button B** to perform a fragment transaction to change FragmentB to FragmentC (the new fragment we're navigating to)

```
buttonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_b, new FragmentC(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
        ft.commit(); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Great idea.
To have a through example for this, just create a navigation drawer project in Android Studio.
You might just have to switch it from sideways to top-bottom style.